# Create Google Calendar event with conference using Google api

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to create Google Calendar events via my NodeJS app. The following code works, and creates an event as expected, but without the conference. The response doesn't have any errors or relevant info regarding the conference, it's just not there.

```
response = await calendar.events.insert({
  auth : oauth2Client,
  calendarId : req.body.user,
  requestBody : {
    summary : summary,
    description : description,
    location : location,
    colorId : "6",
    start : {dateTime : new Date(startDateTime)},
    end : {dateTime : new Date(endDateTime)},
    attendees : attendees,
    sendNotifications : true,
    conferenceDataVersion : 1,
    conferenceData : {
      createRequest :
          {conferenceSolutionKey : {type : "hangoutsMeet"}, requestId : id}
    },
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. I moved conferenceDataVersion outside the request body.

```
const event = {
            summary: summary,
            description: description,
            location: location,
            colorId: "6",
            start: {
                dateTime: new Date(startDateTime)
            },
            end: {
                dateTime: new Date(endDateTime)
            },
            attendees: attendees,
            sendNotifications: true,
            conferenceData: {
                createRequest: {
                    conferenceSolutionKey: {
                        type: "hangoutsMeet"
                    },
                    requestId: id
                }
            },
        }
        response = await calendar.events.insert({
            auth: oauth2Client,
            calendarId: req.body.user,
            resource: event,
            conferenceDataVersion: 1
        });
```